# T-SQL dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, pivot

Ok I have a table that looks like this

```
ItemID | ColumnName | Value
1      | name       | Peter
1      | phone      | 12345678
1      | email      | peter@host.com
2      | name       | John
2      | phone      | 87654321
2      | email      | john@host.com
3      | name       | Sarah
3      | phone      | 55667788
3      | email      | sarah@host.com
```

Now I need to turn that into this:

```
ItemID | name  | phone    | email
1      | Peter | 12345678 | peter@host.com
2      | John  | 87654321 | john@host.com
3      | Sarah | 55667788 | sarah@host.com
```

I have been looking at dynamic pivot examples, but it seems Im not able to fit them into my scenario.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see a pivot in your data. You've listed regular column names & values in an odd way in the first block, and normally in the second.

Comment: And if the first block represent your actual data, then why is it stored like that as opposed to normalized?

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic PIVOT for this data? This can be achieved by a static PIVOT (check my answer). Is it because you are expecting ColumnName to have values other than name, phone and email?

Comment: Yes the ColumnNames and the number of Columns will change. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Same reason the data is not normalized.

Comment: If the names/number of columns will change, change your sample data and expected results accordingly. As it is, a static pivot will satisfy the problem as you've posed it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have a look at the following example

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
        ID INT,
        ColumnName VARCHAR(250),
        Value VARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 1,'name','Peter' 
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 1,'phone','12345678' 
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 1,'email','peter@host.com' 
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 2,'name','John' 
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 2,'phone','87654321' 
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 2,'email','john@host.com' 
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 3,'name','Sarah' 
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 3,'phone','55667788' 
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 3,'email','sarah@host.com' 

---I assumed your tablename as TESTTABLE--- 
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000) 
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000) 

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT 
                                '],[' + t.ColumnName 
                        FROM    #Table AS t 
                        --ORDER BY '],[' + t.ID 
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']' 

SELECT  @cols

SET @query = N'SELECT ID,'+ @cols +' FROM 
(SELECT t1.ID,t1.ColumnName , t1.Value FROM #Table AS t1) p 
PIVOT (MAX([Value]) FOR ColumnName IN ( '+ @cols +' )) 
AS pvt;' 

EXECUTE(@query)

DROP TABLE #Table
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

SQL Server 2005+

```
 ;with 
        cte_name  as(select * from <table> where ColumnName='name'),
        cte_phone as(select * from <table> where ColumnName='phone'),
        cte_email as(select * from <table> where ColumnName='email')
  select n.ItemID,n.Value [Name],p.Value [Phone],e.Value [Email] 
  from  cte_name n
  join  cte_phone p
  on    n.ItemID=p.ItemID
  join  cte_email e
  on    n.ItemID=e.ItemID
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8eb00/1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic pivot, becuase it will be a different table. Simply do something like this:

```
name    phone   email
---------------------------------
Peter            
        123456
                 peter@host.com
```

Check this [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a3ac/8)

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.ItemID, n.Value as 'name', p.Value as 'phone', e.Value as 'email'
FROM UserData u
INNER JOIN(
SELECT ItemID, Value 
FROM UserData WHERE ColumnName = 'name') n ON n.ItemID = u.ItemID
INNER JOIN(
SELECT ItemID, Value 
FROM UserData WHERE ColumnName = 'phone') p ON p.ItemID = u.ItemID
INNER JOIN(
SELECT ItemID, Value 
FROM UserData WHERE ColumnName = 'email') e ON e.ItemID = u.ItemID
```

Comment: The problem is that the ColumnNames are dynamic. Both their names and the number of columns will differ.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a query I'm using for my contactlist :)

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT Contact_Id AS CT
          , [Age]
          , [Sex]
          , [State]
          , [Country]
          , [Keyword]
          , [Married]
          , [Kids]
          , [Car]
     FROM
         (SELECT c.PropertyName
               , c.ValueString
               , c.Contact_Id
          FROM
              ContactProfiles c) AS ctp
         PIVOT (max(ctp.ValueString) FOR PropertyName IN ([Age], [Sex], [State], [Country], [Keyword], [Married], [Kids], [Car])) AS PivotTable
         ) AS pvt

WHERE
    pvt.[Age] > 18
    AND (pvt.[State] = 'CA' OR pvt.[State] = 'NY')
    AND pvt.[Sex] = 'F'
    --*AND pvt.[Keyword] LIKE '%B;%'
    AND pvt.[Married] = 'True'
    AND pvt.[Kids] > 0
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT ItemID, name, phone, email
FROM
(SELECT [ItemID] ,[ColumnName] ,[Value] FROM Item) Item
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR ColumnName IN (name, phone, email) ) as pvt
```

Comment: The problem is that the ColumnNames are dynamic. Both their names and the number of columns will differ.