# query to combine multiple columns in one columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have table which contain the following information. [image]

I want to run a query and show only one line. something like this
[image]

I try to use a case statement, However i maybe have other employee who work in different state, and i do not want to list 50 state since most of employee may only work 2-3 state, but in different state. Any help will appreciate. Thanks

Comment: You should use Pivot.

Comment: this will also require the use of dynamic SQL since the number of columns is unknown [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot) [Example2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean something like stuff and XML PATH? Can you help me with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to pivot on multiple columns, my suggestion would be to first look at unpivoting the `State`, `StateWages` and `StateTax` columns then apply the PIVOT function.

You didn't specify what version of SQL Server you are using but you can use either UNPIVOT to CROSS APPLY to convert these multiple columns into rows. The syntax will be similar to:

```
select PRCo, Employee, 
  col = c.col + cast(seq as varchar(50)),
  c.value
from
(
  select PRCo, Employee, State, StateWages, StateTax,
    row_number() over(partition by PRCo, Employee
                      order by state) seq
  from yourtable
) d
cross apply
(
  select 'State', State union all
  select 'StateWages', cast(StateWages as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'StateTax', cast(StateTax as varchar(10))
) c (col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6d98/2). You'll notice that before I implemented the CROSS APPLY, I used a subquery with `row_number()` to create a unique value for each row per employee.  The reason for doing this is so you can return the multiple state columns, etc.   Once you have done this you can use PIVOT:

```
select PRCo, Employee, 
  State1, StateWages1, StateTax1,
  State2, StateWages2, StateTax2
from
(
  select PRCo, Employee, 
    col = c.col + cast(seq as varchar(50)),
    c.value
  from
  (
    select PRCo, Employee, State, StateWages, StateTax,
      row_number() over(partition by PRCo, Employee
                        order by state) seq
    from yourtable
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select 'State', State union all
    select 'StateWages', cast(StateWages as varchar(10)) union all
    select 'StateTax', cast(StateTax as varchar(10))
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (State1, StateWages1, StateTax1,
              State2, StateWages2, StateTax2)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6d98/3).  The above version works great if you have a limited number of value but it sounds like you need a dynamic solution.  Using the code above you can easily convert it to dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                        select row_number() 
                            over(partition by PRCo, Employee
                                 order by state) seq
                        from yourtable
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'State', 1 union all
                      select 'StateWages', 2 union all
                      select 'StateTax', 3
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, so, seq
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = N'SELECT PRCo, Employee, ' + @cols + N' 
            from 
            (
              select PRCo, Employee, 
                col = c.col + cast(seq as varchar(50)),
                c.value
              from
              (
                select PRCo, Employee, State, StateWages, StateTax,
                  row_number() over(partition by PRCo, Employee
                                    order by state) seq
                from yourtable
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                select ''State'', State union all
                select ''StateWages'', cast(StateWages as varchar(10)) union all
                select ''StateTax'', cast(StateTax as varchar(10))
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6d98/8). Both versions will give a result:

```
| PRCO | EMPLOYEE | STATE1 | STATEWAGES1 | STATETAX1 | STATE2 | STATEWAGES2 | STATETAX2 |
|------|----------|--------|-------------|-----------|--------|-------------|-----------|
|    1 |      304 |     CA |    20162.03 |    804.42 |     IN |    20162.03 |    665.90 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try and let you know. :)