# Convert row to columns SQL dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table Dev with the data below

```
YYYMMDD   Atest  BTest   CTest

20150525   100    200    300
20150526   110    210    310
20150527   120    220    320
```

I need output like below

```
     xyz  20150525  201050526  20150527

    Atest 100       110         120
    BTest 200        210        220
    CTest 300        310        320
```

How can i achieve above result set. My table Dev will grow and i need the result set table to build columns dynamically and display the data as required.
Any help is appreciated. If you suggest pivot, may i know what field should i use for aggregation and how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: What field should i use for aggregation here like min(choice) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to unpivot your table and after that pivot again. This is the key idea:

```
select * from TableName
unpivot(v for xyz in([Atest],[Btest],[Ctest]))u
pivot(max(v) for yyyymmdd in([20150525],[20150526],[20150527]))p
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a675c/1

As for dynamic sql, you can find many example of how you can use `STUFF` function to concatenate distinct dates in one string and construct dynamic query. For instance [T-SQL dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot)

Comment: Thanks Nakeuri. That worked. I will try to use STUFF function now.