# Joining tables and LEFT JOIN as new Columns in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row

In this sample I have two tables containing data for my Customer and Products that a office supply shop has. which is seen below:

[image] [image]

The Above tables primarily functions to supply the required data for the third table which is the Orders table

[image]

Using the orders table, I can get a quick summary for reports that I need from customer and products table. The problem starts when I want to see the purchase count of each customer per item.

Like these tables for example.

[image]

Using the tables above, I need to create a report that shows the purchase count of each customer per item.

Like this.

[image]

I have used `CTE` to show items by `Row_number` but the code I have now is quite too long, I'm currently testing some way to do this the most efficient and most concise way. If someone can teach me how to do this the shorter way that would be great.

I'm not quite sure if my question's title is correct, I'll change it if it seems incorrect.

Comment: it's better to post data that can be copy and pasted rather than images, people can then try to replicate it without manually typing out your data. Better still, write a script that will populate a temp table with your sample data and show the issue with your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Step one would be to start off with your base query. This gives you the final report information but in the wrong format. All that is needed now is to pivot it.

```
Select cus_Name, prod_Name, SUM(ord_Qty)
from Orders o
inner join Customers c on c.cus_ID = o.cus_ID
inner join Products p on p.prod_ID = o.Prod_ID
GROUP BY cus_Name, prod_Name
```

**UPDATED**

Pivoting this is more interesting as presumably the number of Products is not fixed. You therefore need to write a dynamic pivot to determine the columns based on the products ! Please note I haven't tested the below, but you should get the idea. Please refer to the plethora of posts on [dynamic pivots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot) for further questions on Pivots:

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e907/41)

```
DECLARE @colsForSelect VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @colsForPivot VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @colsForSelect = ISNULL(@colsForSelect + ',','') + ' ISNULL([' + prod_Name + '],0) AS [' + prod_Name + ']',
        @colsForPivot = ISNULL(@colsForPivot + ',','') + ' [' + prod_Name + ']'
FROM    Products

SET @query = N'SELECT cus_Name,'+ @colsForSelect +' 
FROM (    
     Select cus_Name, prod_Name, SUM(ord_Qty) as sum_ord_Qty
     from Orders o
     inner join Customers c on c.cus_ID = o.cus_ID
     inner join Products p on p.prod_ID = o.Prod_ID
     GROUP BY cus_Name, prod_Name
) p 
PIVOT (MAX([sum_ord_Qty]) FOR prod_Name IN ( '+ @colsForPivot +' )) 
AS pvt;'

EXECUTE(@query);
```

Comment: I get the gist of what I should do with your answer but, I don't get the desired output using the code. The code outputs the products that are involved in the transaction in a single column, which is a little bit off for my desired output.

Comment: @chloe. It will be the pivot. Have a read how the pivot works. I will try to update my answer in the next few hours.

Comment: @Chloe I have updated the answer to include a SQLFiddle example. This is now working as expected\asked.

Comment: I'm trying to use a `WHERE` clause in the query now but i can't seem to make it work. Can you help me again how to do it? or I'll make another question for that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add the WHERE clause after the last INNER JOIN and before the GROUP BY. Can you can explain in more detail what you are trying to do ?

Comment: In the Final Report, I'm tying to add another 2 more columns which will SUM the price multiplied by ordered quantity of items. which depends if the items was purchased by cash or check. I'm currently using `SUM(CASE WHEN  ... ` for this condition. I added the new column _ord_PurchaseType_ in the Orders Table which is inputted by either **cash** or **check**  , column `prod_Price` is also added in the Products table

Comment: Bit difficult to do this in the comments. Best make another question like you did above and give you expected answer and what you have tried

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, I'll comment the link later.

Comment: I just posted the question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975910/pivot-columns-in-sql-server-with-their-sum) @sarin