# SQL query which returns variable number of columns for each record combining multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on an SQL query which should return data having same or different number of columns for each row

For example, I have the following data which comes from a CTE as follows

```
 With CTE 
    As(

    select distinct
    b.Acc_Num,
a.Type
    ,a.START
     ,a.END
    ,a.USAGE
    from USAGE_DETAIL a 
    join Table2 b on b.CUSTOMER_TKN=a.CUSTOMER_TKN
    )
    Select * from CTE Order By Acc_num
```

Result is

```
Acc_Num  Type  Start     End       Usage
100       A    1/1/10    1/1/15    100.00
100       A    3/1/10    3/1/15    200.00
100       A    2/1/10    2/1/15    300.00
200       A    1/1/10    1/1/15    150.00
200       A    3/1/10    3/1/15    250.00
300       A    1/1/10    1/1/15    1000.00
300       A    3/1/10    3/1/15    2000.00
```

In the above table, I have multiple records for each Acc_Num and I want to group all the records with same Acc_num and create additional columns depending on the number of records for each acc_num and result should like the following

```
100       A    1/1/10    1/1/15    100.00    3/1/10    3/1/15    200.00   2/1/10    2/1/15    300.00    
200       A    1/1/10    1/1/15    150.00    3/1/10    3/1/15    250.00
300       A    1/1/10    1/1/15    1000.00   3/1/10    3/1/15    2000.00
```

I am not sure if it is possible to return variable number of columns for a single set of data.

**May I know a way to solve this?**

Comment: You will need to look at Dynamic SQL and a pivot; as you have a unknown number of columns.  Stack has several examples already: here's one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot  and another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are pivoting multiple columns (3 in this series) in which dynamic SQL is required anyways, it may be easiest to just use dynamic SQL alone.

```
DECLARE @Max INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Acc_Num, Type FROM Records) T)
DECLARE @Index INT = 0, @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'SELECT Acc_Num, Type'
WHILE @Index < @Max BEGIN
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
    DECLARE @IndexChar VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Index)
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ',MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + @IndexChar + ' THEN [Start] ELSE NULL END) AS [Start' + @IndexChar + ']'
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ',MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + @IndexChar + ' THEN [End] ELSE NULL END) AS [End' + @IndexChar + ']'
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ',MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + @IndexChar + ' THEN [Usage] ELSE NULL END) AS [Usage' + @IndexChar + ']'
END
SET @Sql = @Sql + ' FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Acc_Num ORDER BY Start) AS RowNum FROM Records) T GROUP BY Acc_Num, Type'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

This results in:

```
Acc_Num     Type Start1     End1       Usage1                Start2     End2       Usage2                Start3     End3       Usage3
----------- ---- ---------- ---------- --------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
100         A    2010-01-01 2015-01-01 100.00                2010-02-01 2015-02-01 300.00                2010-03-01 2015-03-01 200.00
200         A    2010-01-01 2015-01-01 150.00                2010-03-01 2015-03-01 250.00                NULL       NULL       NULL
300         A    2010-01-01 2015-01-01 1000.00               2010-03-01 2015-03-01 2000.00               NULL       NULL       NULL
```

**UPDATE**

Based on you source data, I would just replace the sub-queries:

```
DECLARE @Max INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        b.Acc_Num,
        a.Type
    FROM USAGE_DETAIL a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON b.CUSTOMER_TKN=a.CUSTOMER_TKN
    ) T)
DECLARE @Index INT = 0, @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @Sql = @Sql + 'SELECT Acc_Num, Type'
WHILE @Index < @Max BEGIN
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
    DECLARE @IndexChar VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Index)
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ',MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + @IndexChar + ' THEN [Start] ELSE NULL END) AS [Start' + @IndexChar + ']'
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ',MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + @IndexChar + ' THEN [End] ELSE NULL END) AS [End' + @IndexChar + ']'
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ',MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = ' + @IndexChar + ' THEN [Usage] ELSE NULL END) AS [Usage' + @IndexChar + ']'
END
SET @Sql = @Sql + ' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT b.Acc_Num, a.Type, a.[START], a.[END], a.[USAGE], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.Acc_Num ORDER BY a.[Start]) AS RowNum FROM USAGE_DETAIL a INNER JOIN Table2 b ON b.CUSTOMER_TKN=a.CUSTOMER_TKN) T GROUP BY Acc_Num, Type'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: Thank you and Can you suggest a way to use this with Common Table Expression(CTE) as my original data comes from multiple tables from a read-only database?

Comment: You can either put the CTE expressions before the SELECT in the dynamic query or merge the multiple queries into the sub-query when the row number is added. You'll need to do this twice since the @Max is important to calculate first. You could also just drop all the output from your multiple databases into a temp table, then just change "Records" to the temp table.

Comment: That's a read-only database and I cannot create a Temp table and with regards to the first suggestion, `Records` should be replaced with CTE which doesn't exist when @Max is declared

Comment: I have edited the question just in case you want to take a look at

Comment: By temp table, I mean something like `#Records` that would be temporarily created in tempdb instead of the read-only databases you reference. Are you saying you don't have access to that either?

Comment: Just posted update with sub-queries using your source table

Comment: Thank you but this seems like a solution by I still have issues as it says`The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.`