# How do I display column data in rows grouping by column values using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm querying a table which holds values in the following format:

```
Name       Amount
-----------------
Dside      75
Dside      125 
Ex         75
Ex         125
Fin        75
Fin        125
Fin        80
```

I need to query the table and return the results in the following format:

```
Name  Amount1  Amount2  Amount3
------------------------------
Dside 75       125
Ex    75       125
Fin   55       130      80
```

The amount could go on for 5 or 6 columns - it depends on what data is captured.

Can anybody help?

Comment: A select always return a fixed number of columns, independent of any data in the table.

Comment: what's the datatype for Amount in database "int" or "Money"?

Comment: Is there any chance you can be more specific using the data from my question?!

Comment: @user5321278 I have answer, check it out. You no need to worry about amount column because the soultion which i gave you is dynamic up to n number of columns based on the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have created some sample query to get the appropriate result. I integrate the EricZ solution. This query don't have limit for amount you can have n number of amount for Name.

```
Declare @MaxColumnCount int
--Get max column count
select @MaxColumnCount = Max(CountName) from (
Select COUNT(Name) as CountName from [dbo].[SamplePivot] group by Name
)MaxCount
--print @MaxColumnCount

--Create columnname.
Declare @column_list nvarchar(max)
Declare @id_list nvarchar(max)
Declare @table table(id int,ColumnName nvarchar(max))
Declare @increment int = 1
while(@increment!=@MaxColumnCount)
begin
insert into @table values(@increment, 'Amount'+CAST(@increment as varchar))
set @increment = @increment +1
end
insert into @table values(@increment, 'Amount'+CAST(@increment as varchar))

--select * from @table

--Now combine all column name
select @column_list  = COALESCE(@column_list + ',['+cast(id as varchar)+'] as [' + ColumnName + ']', '['+cast(id as varchar)+'] as [' + ColumnName + ']')
, @id_list = COALESCE(@id_list + ',['+cast(id as varchar)+']', '['+cast(id as varchar)+']')
from @table

print @column_list
print @id_list
--Use pivot dynamic query
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Set @sql = 'WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [Name], [Amount],
    ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY Amount)
  FROM [dbo].[SamplePivot]
)
SELECT Name, '+@column_list+' 
FROM (SELECT [Name] ,[Amount] ,[ID] FROM cte) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (MAX(Amount) FOR [ID] IN ('+@id_list+')) as pvt '

Print @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

[**SQL Fidde DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e0a4/1)

Comment: i will test these solutions and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to display up to 6 `[Amount]` as clouumns. If you have more than 6 Amount per [Name] or it's dynamic, you may look into this answer [T-SQL dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot)

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [Name], [Amount],
    ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY Amount)
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT Name, [1] AS Amount1, [2] AS Amount2, [3] AS Amount3, [4] AS Amount4,[5] AS Amount5, [6] AS Amount6
FROM (SELECT [Name] ,[Amount] ,[ID] FROM cte) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (MAX(Amount) FOR [ID] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])) as pvt
```

[**SQL Fidde DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70bae7/9)

Comment: i will test these solutions and get back to you!