# Pivot table query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have table as shown below. I need to get the values corresponding to maximum date timestamp for each distinct element and convert the rows to columns using SQL Server 2005 or higher. The column name values (i.e. columns A1, A2, A3 are dynamic and can change depending on data available)

Base table (from a resulting query)

```
Id  Name    Value   DateTimeStamp
--------------------------------------
1   A1  5   Nov 14 2011 03:12:12:947PM
1   A1  6   Nov 15 2011 03:12:12:947PM
1   A2  7   Nov 14 2011 03:12:12:947PM
1   A2  8   Nov 15 2011 03:12:12:947PM
1   A3  9   Nov 14 2011 03:12:12:947PM
2   A3  10  Nov 15 2011 03:12:12:947PM
2   A1  1   Nov 14 2011 03:12:12:947PM
2   A1  2   Nov 15 2011 03:12:12:947PM
2   A2  3   Nov 14 2011 03:12:12:947PM
2   A2  4   Nov 15 2011 03:12:12:947PM
2   A3  5   Nov 14 2011 03:12:12:947PM
2   A3  6   Nov 15 2011 03:12:12:947PM
```

Desired output:

```
Id  A1  A2  A3
---------------
1   6   8   10
2   2   4   6
```

Comment: Does name column have limited number of values? Also, what is the datatype for DateTimeStamp column?

Comment: Sorry the column names are dynamic as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL dynamic pivot].  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot) Note that you would need to join back the pivot resutls to table to get the value corresponding to the max datetime.

Comment: Do not want to use dynamic query. Any solutions available using static query.

Comment: You have number of values that you do not know in advance. How do you expect static query to work?

Comment: If you use a static query you need to pre-allow for all possible columns

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [dynamic crosstab:](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/)

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bb249/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT
    Id' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
    ', MAX(CASE WHEN Name = ''' + Name +  ''' THEN Value END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Name) + CHAR(10)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM tbl) t
ORDER BY Name

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM (
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id, Name ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC)
    FROM tbl
) t
WHERE Rn = 1
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY Id'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Any possible solution without the use of dynamic query. the problem is i need to join the results to another subquery. Your effort is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since you have unknown number of `Name`s, you can't do this without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can try inserting the result to a temporary table.