# In SQL Server how should i pivot for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
**branch**      **category**     **sales**    **Stock**   **Target**
Mumbai            Panel              5           10          8
Mumbai            AC                 7           15          10
Mumbai            Ref                8           3           12
Delhi             Panel              10          15          11
Delhi             AC                 7           10          7
Delhi             Ref                3           8           9
```

The above is my Query table i want the desired output to be in the form as given in the table below

```
**Branch**       **qty**    **Panel**      **AC**       **Ref**
Mumbai           sale          5             7             8
Mumbai           Stock         10            15            3
Mumbai          Target         8             10            12
Delhi            Sale          10            7             3
Delhi            Stock         15            10            8
Delhi           Target         11            7             9
```

Comment: You should write dynamic query. Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12210890/6468577

Comment: Sorry i posted in it a wrong manner, ill correct it and repost it