# SQL Server: Combine multiple rows into one with no overlap but new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Table "Details" like this:

```
    ID         |        BookID         |        Genre
    _____________________________________________________
    1          |         12            |         AB
    1          |         05            |         AC
    2          |         12            |         AB
    2          |         08            |         BB
```

Is there any way to combine the rows in this format:

```
    ID  | BookID1 | Genre1  | BookID2 | Genre2
    _____________________________________________________
    1   | 12      | AB      | 05      |   AC
    2   | 12      | AB      | 08      |   BB
```

I need to do it in such a format to add the respective columns to a stored procedure.

I generally would love to include some code or attempts but I'm clueless at this moment.

Not a Duplicate of the below:
[T-SQL dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot)

1st difference im not using tsql

2nd difference is the structure of the table which can't be applied to mine.

My values are **not** going to be **column headers** instead they are gonna generate *new* columns such as :

```
    ID  | BookID1 | Genre1  | BookID2 | Genre2  | BookID3 | Genre3  | BookID4 | Genre4
    1   | 05      | Horror  | 12      | Horror  | 03      | Drama   |         | 
    2   | 05      | Horror  | 15      | Advent  | 03      | Drama   | 112     | RomCom
```

3rd Im not able to grasp the structure since I have zero knowledge of pivot tables

Comment: Is there a well-known number of columns?

Comment: You'll probably need dynamic SQL for this

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/3270427

Comment: this might help: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx

Comment: @McNets max number of repetitions is 10

Comment: @Looking_for_answers the tables/code in the page are not visible

Comment: Please look at McNets comment it will take you to another question like this and you may find what you are looking for.

Comment: @helpwanted161 *max  number of repetitions* implies a dynamic number of repititions. In that case, you need a dynamic pivot.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate.. And Pivot is not the solution here.

Comment: BookId - BookGenre is 1-1 relationship, isn't it?

Comment: Nope not necessarily @TriV

Comment: Usually this is *easy* to do in a reporting tool or an application front-end, but complex to do in a T-SQL stored procedure. Is there a good **reason** why you're trying to do it down in the database?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever cause what I showed is just an example. I have about 60 columns that are generated from several databases across different servers and this is just a chunk of it. Plus going forward for any alterations (they will occur) it would be easier for me to edit within sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those with a case similar to mine.

The below link is a huge help :

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/973727-sql-how-to-convert-multiple-rows-into-single-rows-with-more-columns

Answer (score 1):

Try a dynamic sql query

```
CREATE TABLE #BookGenreMapping
(
   Id int,
   BookId int,
   Genre varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #BookGenreMapping VALUES (1,12,'AB'),(1,05,'AC'),(2,12,'AB'),(2,08,'BC'),(2,09,'BCD')
DECLARE @HeaderAll nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ColumnPivotBookId nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ColumnPivotGenre nvarchar(max)

;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT *, 
   CONCAT('BookID' ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY bgm.Id ORDER BY bgm.BookId)) AS BookGroupId,
   CONCAT('BookGroupGenre' ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY bgm.Id ORDER BY bgm.BookId)) AS BookGroupGenre
   FROM #BookGenreMapping bgm
),
temp1 AS 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT t.BookGroupId, t.BookGroupGenre FROM temp t
)
SELECT @HeaderAll = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',',t.BookGroupId, ',', t.BookGroupGenre) FROM temp1 t FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,''),
     @ColumnPivotBookId =  STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',',t.BookGroupId) FROM temp1 t FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,''),
     @ColumnPivotGenre =  STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', t.BookGroupGenre) FROM temp1 t FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')

--SELECT @HeaderAll, @ColumnPivotBookId, @ColumnPivotGenre


DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = CONCAT(
      ';WITH temp AS
      (
         SELECT *, 
         CONCAT(''','BookID',''' ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY bgm.Id ORDER BY bgm.BookId)) AS BookGroupId,
         CONCAT(''','BookGroupGenre',''' ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY bgm.Id ORDER BY bgm.BookId)) AS BookGroupGenre
         FROM #BookGenreMapping bgm
      )
      SELECT pt1.Id, ',@HeaderAll,' FROM
      (
          SELECT Id, ',@ColumnPivotBookId,' FROM 
          (
            SELECT t.Id, t.BookId, t.BookGroupId FROM temp t
          ) src
          PIVOT
          (
            MIN(BookId) FOR BookGroupId IN (',@ColumnPivotBookId,')    
          ) pvt
       ) pt1
       INNER JOIN
       (
          SELECT Id, ',@ColumnPivotGenre,' FROM 
          (
            SELECT t.Id, t.Genre, t.BookGroupGenre FROM temp t
          ) src
          PIVOT
          (
            MIN(Genre) FOR BookGroupGenre IN (',@ColumnPivotGenre,')    
          ) pvt
       ) pt2 ON pt1.Id = pt2.Id'
       )

PRINT @query
exec(@query)


DROP TABLE #BookGenreMapping
```