# TSQL Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a "small" issue with a PIVOT SQL script. I have based my current solution on a similar question here [Dynamic PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot)  .

I have managed to write the PIVOT script and largely it is ok. However, my situation is this, instead of getting the unique entries onto single rows, the script outputs something like this

```
ListingEntryId   Address        Employees   Location
1                NULL           NULL        Nottingham
1                Canal Street   NULL        NULL
1                NULL           3           NULL
2                NULL           NULL        London
2                Camden         NULL        NULL
2                NULL           12          NULL
```

Whereas the results I am looking for should look something like this

```
ListingEntryId   Address        Employees   Location
1                Canal Street   3           Nottingham
2                Camden         12          London
```

Here's the script

```
DECLARE @listingId INT = 1;
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT LEV.ListingColumnId, LEV.ListingEntryId, LE.CreatedBy, LEV.EntryValue, LD.ColumnTitle, LD.[Index]
INTO #ListingTable
FROM ListingEntryValue LEV LEFT OUTER JOIN 
ListingEntry LE ON LEV.ListingEntryId=LE.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
ListingDefinition LD ON LEV.ListingColumnId = LD.Id
WHERE LE.ListingId = @listingId;

SELECT * FROM #ListingTable;

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT ',' + QUOTENAME(LT.ColumnTitle) FROM #ListingTable LT
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,1,'')
SELECT @cols;

SET @query = 'SELECT ListingEntryId,' + @cols + ' FROM (SELECT ListingEntryId, ListingColumnId, EntryValue, ColumnTitle, [Index] FROM #ListingTable LT) x
PIVOT (MAX(EntryValue) FOR ColumnTitle IN (' + @cols + ')
) p'

PRINT @query
EXECUTE(@query);


DROP TABLE #ListingTable
```

I'll be grateful for some pointers that can help me sort this out. I've made a [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f31776/4/0) which for some strange reason doesn't output anything but all the code to generate the schema is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit the fields in the PIVOT to only the required elements (X, Y, Value)

```
SET @query = 'SELECT ListingEntryId,' + @cols + ' FROM (SELECT ListingEntryId, EntryValue, ColumnTitle FROM #ListingTable LT) x
PIVOT (MAX(EntryValue) FOR ColumnTitle IN (' + @cols + ')
) p'
```

Returns

```
ListingEntryId  Address         Employees   Location
1               Canal Street    3           Nottingham
2               Camden          12          London
```

Comment: @ObiOnuorah Happy it helped