# How to add a variable to auto pickup column row names and turn it into new column headers using Pivot query in Oracle Sql developer

Tags: pivot-table, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-pivot

Initial table students

```
NAME     School    Class
 John     Hs      English
 Steve    Hs      Maths
 Matthew  Hs      Science
 Jim      Hs      History
```

Output Needed: I need the query to auto pick up Name column data from initial table and change it to column headers in output and since the names will continuously change i cannot hard code the names using simple pivot query. I am new to pivot queries so I wanted to request if someone can help me out. Thank You.

```
School  John     Steve  Matthew  Jim
Hs      English  Maths  Science  History
```

Here's what i tried: *Note( I am trying to use this query in Oracle Sql Developer to achieve the output format)

```
declare 
        sqlqry clob;
        cols clob;
  begin 
  select listagg('''' || NAME || ''' as "' || NAME || '"', ',') within group   (order by NAME)
  into cols
  from (select distinct NAME from Students);
  sqlqry := 
  '
   select * from(select NAME,SCHOOL,CLASS from Students)
   pivot(MAX(CLASS) FOR NAME IN (' || cols || ')
   )';
   execute immediate sqlqry;
   end;
```

Comment: Please update your question tags. Microsoft `sql-server` conflicts with `oracle-sqldeveloper`. You are trying to achieve a "dynamic pivot", there are several examples on this site already such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot).

Comment: Thank You i will update the tags and I did try the things in the link that you provided but it didnt work for me

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question as well as the error or unexpected result you encountered. A full [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is very much preferred.

Comment: Hi Sander, I have added my attempt into the question. Thank you for all the help that you have been providing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Pivot Query using Sql Developer Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694461/dynamic-pivot-query-using-sql-developer-oracle)