# Turn a Concatenated Row into a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT  
  b_Name+' | '+Entity+' | '+cast(A_Date as varchar) as [top]  -- Colum 
  ,b_Name  -- Rows
  ,[Task_Category] -- Rows 
  ,[Fcn_Name] -- Rows
  ,[Task]  -- Rows
  ,[Task_ID] -- Rows
  ,[Owner] -- Rows
  ,[RAG_Status] -- Rows
   FROM [Task]
```

I'm trying to make the concatenated [TOP] into column headings but leave the rest into rows.
I'm still learning SQL so, please be patent with me. lol

```
  SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
b_Name+' | '+Entity+' | '+cast(A_Date as varchar) as [top]  -- Colum 
      ,b_Name  -- Rows
      ,[Task_Category] -- Rows 
      ,[Fcn_Name] -- Rows
      ,[Task]  -- Rows
      ,[Task_ID] -- Rows
      ,[Owner] -- Rows
      ,[RAG_Status] -- Rows
     FROM [IntegrationDBdev].[dbo].[Task_Acquisition]
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(AVG(task) FOR ????
IN(
??????

) ) AS PivotTable;
```

I've tried the above but not sure what to put in the pivot

Comment: required reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: At first glance the solution requires a `pivot` and dynamic SQL. Both can be challenging in SQL on their own... Any chance you can simply the output headers to something more generic like `EntityDate1`, `EntityDate2`, etc.? Also please provide some sample input data and expected result. [Pivot example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#basic-pivot-example) and [dynamic pivot example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210692/t-sql-dynamic-pivot).

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend this to have top as some concatenation in Pivot because in 'IN' condition you will have to have the concatenation as well.

but for your code you can have it like

```
CREATE TABLE Grades(
  [Student] VARCHAR(50),
  [Subject] VARCHAR(50),
  [Marks]   INT
)
GO
 
INSERT INTO Grades VALUES 
('Jacob','Mathematics',100),
('Jacob','Science',95),
('Jacob','Geography',90),
('Amilee','Mathematics',90),
('Amilee','Science',90),
('Amilee','Geography',100)
GO

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    [Student],
    [Subject]+'|'+[Student] as [Test1],
    [Marks]
  FROM Grades
) StudentResults
PIVOT (
  SUM([Marks])
  FOR [Test1]
  IN (
    [Mathematics|Amilee],
    [Science|Amilee],
    [Geography|Amilee],
    [Mathematics|Jacob],
    [Science|Jacob],
    [Geography|Jacob]
  )
) AS PivotTable
```

[image]

I would recommend it to be like

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    [Student],
    [Subject],
    [Marks]
  FROM Grades
) StudentResults
PIVOT (
  SUM([Marks])
  FOR [Subject]
  IN (
    [Mathematics],
    [Science],
    [Geography]
  )
) AS PivotTable
```

which will give result

[image]

Let me know if any more clarificaiton needed.

Comment: IN (
    'Mathematics|Amilee',
   
  )    using sting '' in the in condition but noticed I was actually calling a column. lol